# Deleting many lines using preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Although regexes seem to be a recurrent trouble, I didn't figure out a solution to my problem.

I have a file of many lines (> 75 000), in which I want to replace a lot of them, all between two identifiable patterns (starting_point and ending_point). 
My regex attempt :

```
$filtered = preg_replace('%(#\sstarting_point).+(#\sending_point)%isU',$replacement,$2befiltered);
```

. is now whatever character, including \n. I used %..% as separators because my lines have pretty much anything, but no % (anything includes /,$,-,",spaces,+,{,}) and I was experiencing a "Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset...".

But I can't seem to make it work. I thought maybe pcre in php.ini was the problem, but it doesn't seem so. I tried to use [?U](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), without success. same with .*? as I have read in some places. Maybe I just wrote them wrong, but ..

Anyway, anybody willing to scratch his head on this?

text example (with ... signifying many other lines):

```
whatever
lines
you
can
...
# starting_point
lines/*-
to$_,"
delete+{}=@
...
# ending_point
some
other
lines
...
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace? Every line inbetween starting_point and ending_point?

Comment: yes, exactly, and keep whatever is before or after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work: `%(#\sstarting_point)(.*?)(#\sending_point)%isU`

$matches [2] [0] contains the lines inbetween # starting_point and # ending_point

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtered = preg_replace('/(#\sstarting_point)(.*?)(#\sending_point)/sm', $replacement,$2befiltered);
```

Try this.

Comment: this one did not work :( but I have the solution, thank you for your help!